# Problema con mi clase que usa Mapas

Tags: java, hashmap

Hola hago esta pregunta porque no sé como resolver este ejercicio y he buscado en sitios como resolverlo y **no he encontrado nada**, hago esta pregunta para poder al menos debatir de este ejercicio exacto en internet y que si a alguien le pasa algo igual que lo pueda encontrar
Además, **soy una persona que le cuesta sacar la lógica, así que espero que seais comprensivos de que estoy preguntando porque ya no sé que hacer,**
el caso, es que tengo un ejercicio que dice asi:

Escribe un programa que genere una secuencia de 15 números aleatorios entre 1 y 10.
Según se vayan generando los números se irán introduciendo en una mapa
Map<Integer,Integer> donde la clave representa uno de los números aleatorios
generados, y el valor el número de veces que aparece dicho número en la secuencia.
Un ejemplo del mapa tras la generación de los 15 números aleatorios podría ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces mi código es este, solo lo he hecho en 1 clase:

```
package mapas;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import utilidades.Funciones;

public class p05_mapas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        int [] numeros = new int [15];
        
        Map<Integer,Integer> nums = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        
        int aparacion1 = 0;
        int aparacion2 = 0;
        int aparacion3 = 0;
        int aparacion4 = 0;
        int aparacion5 = 0;
        int aparacion6 = 0;
        int aparacion7 = 0;
        int aparacion8 = 0;
        int aparacion9 = 0;
        int aparacion10 = 0;
        
        
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            int n = Funciones.generarAleatorio(1, 10);
            numeros[i]=n;
            switch (n) {
            case 1:
                aparacion1=aparacion1+1;
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                aparacion2=aparacion2+1;
                break;
                
            case 3:
                aparacion3=aparacion3+1;
                break;

            case 4:
                aparacion4=aparacion4+1;
                break;


            case 5:
                aparacion5=aparacion5+1;
                break;

                
            case 6:
                aparacion6=aparacion6+1;
                break;

                
            case 7:
                aparacion7=aparacion7+1;
                break;
                
            case 8:
                aparacion8=aparacion8+1;
                break;
            case 9:
                aparacion9=aparacion9+1;
                break;
            case 10:
                aparacion10=aparacion10+1;
                break;

                
            }
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                
                
                switch (numeros[j]) {
                case 1:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion1);
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion2);
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion3);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion4);
                    break;


                case 5:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion5);
                    break;

                    
                case 6:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion6);
                    break;

                    
                case 7:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion7);
                    break;
                    
                case 8:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion8);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion9);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    nums.put(numeros[j], aparacion10);
                    break;

                    
                }
                
            }
            
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : nums.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Numero aleatorio: "+ entry.getKey() + " Apariciones: " + entry.getValue());
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

El método generar aleatorio es asi, por si alguien le interesa:

```
public static int generarAleatorio(int desde, int hasta) {
        if (hasta<desde)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hasta debe ser mayor que desde");
        
        Random r=new Random();
        int al=r.nextInt(hasta-desde+1); //0..n
        al=al+desde;
                
        return al;
    }
```

**Cuando lo ejecuto, sale más de 15 veces y no sé si lo pilla bien, entonces no sé como resolverlo, lo he intentado cambiar, y aun así no pillo el truco.**

Luego continua el ejercicio pero yo **solo estoy haciendo lo que pone arriba**, la continuación lo pongo debajo por si alguien quiere hacerlo, pero esto ya no lo he hecho:

Una vez creado el mapa anterior, a partir de él:
 Mostrar cuántos números diferentes se han generado.
 Mostrar un listado ordenado de los números aleatorios generados de menor a
mayor (si utilizamos TreeMap ya lo tenemos) junto con el número de veces que
ha aparecido.
 Mostrar un listado ordenado por el número de apariciones (descendente), a
igual número de apariciones ordenar por número (ascendente).
Por ejemplo:

Números diferentes: 5

=== Listado ordenado por número ===

El 1 ha aparecido 4 veces

El 2 ha aparecido 2 veces

El 3 ha aparecido 1 vez

El 7 ha aparecido 2 veces

El 10 ha aparecido 6 veces

=== Listado ordenado por número de apariciones ===

6 apariciones del número 10

4 apariciones del número 1

2 apariciones del número 2

2 apariciones del número 7

1 aparición del número 1

Comment: Y si fueran 5 millones de número en vez de 15, escribirías 5 millones de case's??. Un  `map` tiene `key` y `value`, y una key es única. 1) haces un for que recorra del 0 al 14. 2) Generas un numero aleatorio 3) Preguntas si está en el map guardado (containsKey) 4) Si existe, sumas 1 a su value 5) Si no existe, lo agregas con un value de 1 y la key es el valor aleatorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes crear un método simple que cuente las apariciones de un numero en el array donde obtengas los valores generados aleatoriamente,esto te ahorraria varias lineas de códigos si decidieras ingresar mas de 15 numeros

```
public static int contarApariciones(int[]array,int num){
int cont=0;
for(int i:array){
if(i==num){
  cont++;
}
}return cont;

}
```

al momento de ingresar los numeros en el array debes asegurarte de filtrar los valores únicos en otro array

```
int [] numeros = new int [15];
Map<Integer,Integer> nums = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for (int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++ ) {
   numeros[i]=generarAleatorio(1,10);
}
```

podes usar el método [distinct()](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-stream-distinct-examples/) para ello si tu array generado fuese 1 1 1 2 3 disntinct regresara 1 2 3

```
int[]claves=Arrays.stream(numeros).distinct().toArray();
```

ahora agregas los valores distintos como claves y usas el método creado para contar eso valores dinstintos y colocarlos como valor

```
for (int i:claves ) {
   nums.put(i,contarApariciones(numeros,i));
}
```

[Ejecución](https://www.codiva.io/p/e2ea58ce-c1db-4fd2-8a40-271817bcbefa)